# iPhone 4S, Forever recover mode?

Tags: itunes, iphone, error

I have an iPhone 4S, and it is in recovery Mode, and when I want to restore it, error (1) pop-up. like in photos below
[image: Error and forever recover mode]

I did search on Internet, people say it's an electronic part issue, is it true?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your help,
I did try all, and used TinyUmbrella(exit recovery, launch server...), nothing changed.
many errors accured like 3194... but i solved by editing host file or desactivate Anti-virus and Firewall ....
but error (1), when I start the recovering(both from itunes server or local .ipsw), before the finish of the instaling(when the progress bar appears in my Iphone).

Answer (score 1):

[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS3694#1), error 1 means:

> These errors mean that your device or computer may have a hardware issue that's preventing the update or restore from completing.

I would suggest you try:

- Other usb ports
- Not using a usb hub, plug directly to your machine
- Different computer
- Different (preferably original) usb cable
- Use `TinyUmbrella` and its "exit recovery" option (you probably need to put your device in DFU mode first)

Also make sure you use the latest version of iTunes

---

Finally, if everything else fails, then it could be an actual hardware issue according to reports from other users :/

Comment: Thank you for your help,
I did try all you said, and used TinyUmbrella(exit recovery, launch server...), nothing changed.
many errors accured like 3194... but i solved by editing host file or desactivate Anti-virus and Firewall ....
but error (1), when I start the recovering(both from itunes server or local .ipsw), before the finish of the instaling(when the progress bar appears in my Iphone).

Comment: Did you also try different machines, usb ports and cables? (Sad thing is that I found some references the claim this is a hardware problem and cannot really be fixed. But does not seem like a universal opinion)

Comment: 1. I did try to install the latest version of ios with the latest version of Itunes.
2. I did try to downgrade to 5.1.1, with redsn0w (0.9.11b1 and 0.9.14b2) but the probleme is I dont have SHSH blobs, because iPhone 4s is A5 version.
Any suggestions please

Comment: First, I would say forget about downgrading and try for the latest version. Try restoring with a completely different computer, just to rule out possible specifics machine issues. Also try with a different cable (get one from a friend or so)

Comment: I tried restoring with MAC and PC, different cables, no solution, I think it's a Hardware Failure (some says mother board, others Baseband chip). Anyway Thank you LyK, If I'll get the solution i will post it, if you do post it.

Comment: I am sorry that we did find a solution. I will add the hardware failure as a final explanation.

Comment: This is the solution, it is failed Apple iPhone 4s U18_RF U20_RF Baseband Power IC. its a cheap chip but to repair it is difficult.(as you can see in this Video)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grbGWSV4_ds

Comment: That's unfortunate. Hope you have someone to help with that repair.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes.
2. Check for issues with [third-party security software](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht201413).
3. Make sure that your USB cable, computer, and network are reliable. Then try twice more to restore your iPhone.
4. If you still see the error message, you can [check for outdated or modified software](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204770#outdated) or contact Apple Support.